# brink of error vs brink of mistake

Tags: phrase-request, idioms, phrases

How to fill the gap *"Musician should teeter on the brink of ___ while playing."*

1. error
2. mistake
3. failure

Is any of these alternatives more "idiomatic" for the expression?

The meaning of the sentence above is that a musician should constantly risk a false note. He should be at the edge of his abilities and try to go beyond that. If he doesn't, he cheats the audience.

Comment: According to [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brink+of+error%2Cbrink+of+mistake%2Cbrink+of+failure&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrink%20of%20error%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrink%20of%20failure%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbrink%20of%20error%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrink%20of%20failure%3B%2Cc0), **brink of failure** is much more predominant

Comment: @Void But Google is not a judge. **“Every judgment teeters on the brink of error.”** Quote by Frank Herbert, American sci-fi author.

Comment: Just because 'brink of failure' is predominant, doesn't mean 'brink of error' is incorrect.

Comment: We use 'error' when it is appropriate, and 'failure' when that is. A judgement can place us in error, and an effort can end in failure.

Comment: @Void "On the brink of failure" is a cliché often used in the economic news, eg *the economy is on the brink of failure*. Since the internet is wallpapered with economic news, it is no wonder that this phrase will be used more often than others, as long as other phrases exist and are correct. Metal coins are more common than gold coins, so what? The frequency (or as you call it dominance) of use is impractical or might be even misleading. They prove that the leading phrase exists, nothing more.